# Post a large Byte Array to my Asp.Net Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, post, xamarin.forms, httpclient

First-ever post.
I've been building an app that reads pdf files and images which are converted to byte arrays on xamarin.forms, I've built an API using Azure services and everything works fine, with POST and GET requests, when I am posting small strings.
However, when posting a large byte array from 25MB to 50MB, suddenly it doesn't work. No errors are being printed, I've got no feedback.
Here is my Post Request:

```
private async void SubmitBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream septStream = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("PNewsAppV2.PDFs.PNSep2020.pdf");
        MemoryStream septMemStream = new MemoryStream();
        septStream.CopyTo(septMemStream);
        var septByteArray = septMemStream.ToArray();

        var array = setThumbnail(septStream);
        Models.Image img = new Models.Image()
        {
            Img = array
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(img);

        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));
        MediaTypeFormatter bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        var result = await client.PostAsync("https://pnewsapiv3.azurewebsites.net/api/Images", img, bsonFormatter);
        
        if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Hey!", "Your issue has been added.", "Dope");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", img.Img.Length.ToString(), "Cancel");
        }
    }
```

And here is my ImagesController from my API:

```
[HttpPost]
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 52428800)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Image>> PostImage(Image image)
    {
        _context.Images.Add(image);
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (ImageExists(image.Id))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetImage", new { id = image.Id }, image);
    }
```

I've been struggling to work this out, I just need to figure this one out and I should be done with the app. Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated, and if I've badlly explained myself please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean?  Does it hang?  Timeout?  Throw an exception?  Do you get any HTTP response code?  Have you checked the server logs?  Have you checked the various config settings for request size limits?

Comment: Hi @Jason Thanks for your answer, so I've changed the config settings so that it allows for 50mb, no exception, the HttpStatusCode response says "Internal Server Error" I believe this is prompted when the byte array is too large, because I am able to post a small sized byte array.

Comment: “Internal server error” means there is an error on the server.  Check the logs

Comment: I understand when it says "Error" that there's an error... But the error is prompted only when the byte array has reached a certain size.

Comment: Check the logs.  The exact exception should be in the logs.  Once you know what the exception is you can fix it